# How to get rid of VM line in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to get json file from information on a website using Chrome console (console.log). It gives me additional lines VMxxx:xx. Is there any way to get rid of those lines?

```
        {                                                   VM1616:16
            "16"                                            VM1616:17
        },                                                  VM1616:18
        {                                                   VM1616:16
            "34"                                            VM1616:17
        },                                                  VM1616:18
        {                                                   VM1616:16
            "36"                                            VM1616:17
        },                                                  VM1616:18
        {                                                   VM1616:16
            "37"                                            VM1616:17
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're accessing the Object and printing it with `console.log` stringify it first:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

If you want to maintain the indentation stringify takes some additional parameters:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject, null, 2));
```